# Include uglified files in website publish from Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, npm, gulp, publish

I'm using ASP.NET 4.6 (not 5.0/Core), and because some of the JS libraries I'm interested in are only available via NPM, I'm experimenting with the newish NPM and gulp-based pipelines that MS seems to be recommending. I've mostly managed to get everything working and configured the way that I want, with the caveat that I haven't figured out how to get the resulting minified files published out to the website without checking them into source and including them explicitly in the project. (TypeScript manages to do exactly this, though I've never been entirely clear on how.) And of course, I can always fall back to checking them into source and including them in the project - but I've done that before, in the early days of TypeScript, and I really didn't like it, and it seems like it's not the "right" way to do it.

Any suggestions? Is there a build target or something of that sort that could, say, automatically grab everything from a given specified folder (like the `lib` folder that ASP.NET Core uses, I think), and publish those?

Comment: Don't check minified files into source - instead add a new compilation step to your build script. You should compile your classes, your views, minify your JS and CSS, compile down from TypeScript to JS, LESS to CSS all in your build script.

Comment: @mason - I agree, that's what I want to do. The problem is that I can't do that and still use the built-in VS/msbuild website publishing facilities (which are kind of required in the MS universe). Or at least, I can't figure out how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good description of how to do this here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files.

Short version is that you include this in your .pubxml file(s):

```
 <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CustomFiles Include="..\ExtraFiles\**\*" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>

    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Just needed to find the right Google keywords ("msbuild publish build targets include other files", if you're interested) to turn it up.